# Lazy loading causing 'ngModel' cant find issue

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I saw multiple questions with the same title but in most cases, the author had done some typo. I am clearly hoping not to make the same mistake. I have checked and rechecked the code for the typo but couldn't found any. If that's the case after review then I apologize in advance.

I believe my case is different. I  think the error is happening due to lazy loading (taking guess). I am producing code here.

> **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'location',
    loadChildren: 'app/location/location.module#LocationModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'restaurants',
    loadChildren: 'app/restaurant/restaurant.module#RestaurantModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'menu',
    loadChildren: 'app/menu/menu.module#MenuModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

menu-list.component is part of menu.model.

**menu.model.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { MenuRoutingModule } from './menu-routing.module';
import { MenuListComponent } from './menu-list/menu-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MenuRoutingModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [MenuListComponent]
})
export class MenuModule { }
```

> **menu-routing.module.ts**

```
import { MenuListComponent } from './menu-list/menu-list.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component:MenuListComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MenuRoutingModule { }
```

Getting error in **menu-list.component.html** on following line:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="xyz" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="100">
```

I received following error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="xyz" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="100">
                    "): ng:///MenuModule/MenuListComponent.html@17:27 Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="xyz" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="100">
                    "): ng:///MenuModule/MenuListComponent.html@17:27
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24668)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34621)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34596)
    at eval (compiler.js:34497)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34497)
    at eval (compiler.js:34367)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24668)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34621)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34596)
    at eval (compiler.js:34497)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34497)
    at eval (compiler.js:34367)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595) defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1448 ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1509 next @ core.js:5497 schedulerFn @ core.js:4331 SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:243 SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:190 Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:131 Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:95 Subject.next @ Subject.js:56 EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4311 (anonymous) @ core.js:4771 ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388 Zone.run @ zone.js:138 NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4697 onHandleError @ core.js:4771 ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:392 Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:154
_loop_1 @ zone.js:677 api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:686 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:602 Promise.then (async) scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578 ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410 onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297 ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401 Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232 Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252 scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862 resolvePromise @ zone.js:808 (anonymous) @ zone.js:724 webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:22 (anonymous) @ menu.module.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: What is it that can't be found? The exact text of the error message would help. If it's `xyz` that can't be found, I can't find it either.

Comment: Please post the menu.module.ts

Comment: @TsvetanGanev added error message received in chrome.

Comment: @TomaszKula Added the code.

Comment: @kshetline added error message received in chrome. I added xyz as a place holder. actual value didnt change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import `FormsModule` in your `menu.module.ts`, by adding it to the `@NgModule` `imports` array. It is not enough to import it in the `app.module.ts`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { MenuRoutingModule } from './menu-routing.module';
import { MenuListComponent } from './menu-list/menu-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MenuRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule // <-- add this
  ],
  declarations: [MenuListComponent]
})
export class MenuModule { }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it's not enough just to add FormsModule in app.module.ts? Was I right that due to Lazy Loading MenuModule cant find FormsModule imported by AppModule? If that is the case why we dont have to import BrowserModule in MenuModule.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule the BrowserModule is explained here.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.